# Linking with g++ undefined reference

Tags: c++, class, linker, linker-errors

I've written the following code:

```
//--a.cpp--//
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    void bar();
    virtual void foo()=0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        A::bar();
    }
}
int main()
{
    B *b= new B();
    b->foo();
    return 0;
}

//--b.cpp--//
#include <stdio.h>
class A
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        printf("class A");
    }
}
```

Now I'm comipilng and linking this modules as follow:

```
g++ -c a.cpp
g++ -c b.cpp
g++ -o bin a.o b.o
```

But the `undefined reference error` is raised by linker. I don't understand, why?

Comment: You have a redefinition of class `A` in `b.cpp`, not an implementation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Did you mean that I must to submerse defenition of A into the header?

Comment: Yes put the declaration of `A` into a header file, and put an implementation of `A::bar()` in the `a.cpp` as one usually does.

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined `A::bar()` in `a.cpp`. In `B::foo()` that method is called, but it does not have an implementation. So linker cannot link it.

In `b.cpp` you created another class name `A`, but it is unrelated to the first one. It will not create any problem here, but you will get *Redefinition Error* if you include any one file into another or both files in a third file (although including *.cpp* is uncommon). There must be only one definition of a name in one *Translation Unit*.

Common practice is to declare class in *header file (.hXX)* and implement the methods in *source file (.cXX)*. If you want methods to be `inline`d then you may define in header or explicitly declare the method as *inline*. See [Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) , [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: This is undefined behaviour due to ODR violation - you aren't allowed to have two different class definitions with the same name.  (This is why it's recommended to use anonymous `namespace` for class definitions that are meant to be local to a unit)